# Single chronological feed from multiple tables data with Rails 5

Tags: jquery, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, grails-controller

I have 2 tables Posts & Websites. I have a single feed where I want to display posts and websites together in chronological order.

How can I do that? Currently, I pull separately

**Posts.all** in posts_controller
and
**Websites.all** in websites_controller

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@feed = (@posts + @websites).sort_by {|a| a.created_at}.reverse
```

this simple line solved it!